# Typescript 'T' cannot be used to index type? But T is "keyof" target type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
type foo = {
    asd:""
}

interface FOOS<T = keyof foo> extends foo {
    copy(key: T): foo[T]// error
}
```

`Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'foo'.`

How can I tell typescript that this T can be used as a key for that type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your generic type has a *default* of `keyof foo`, but someone could still instantiate it with any unrelated type: `FOOS<string>, FOOS<unknown>` etc.

Try placing a restriction on `T`:

```
interface FOOS<T extends keyof foo= keyof foo> extends foo {
    copy(key: T): foo[T]// error
}
```